# How to remove � sign from whole site in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have uploaded wordpress site on live , then the one "�" sign is being appearing in between content , but it is fine in local. How to remove please suggest me ? I am not able fix the problem.

Example - Frédèric becomes Fr�d�ric.

Comment: Set the proper charset to UTF-8

Comment: I think site Hacked.

Comment: Most likely your web server is setting a different Content-Type HTTP header than your local server!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your web page also uses the UTF-8 encoding:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

If you use PHP, you can send your own headers in this way (you have to put this before any other output):

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```